# VideoJS HTML5 Video JS How to boost volume above maximum?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, video.js

Its possible there's no solution to this but I thought I'd inquire anyway. Sometimes a video is really quiet and if I turn the volume of my computer up accordingly then other sounds I have become way too loud as a result. It would be nice to be able to boost the volume above maximum.

I did a search on google which literally turned up nothing at all, not even results related to videojs at all in fact. Some videos my Mac is almost at max volume to hear the video's speech well so it would not be feasible to start with everything at a lower volume and adjust accordingly.

I tried with:

```
   var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
   video.volume = 1.0;
```

And setting it to anything above 1.0 but the video then fails to open at all:

```
   var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
   video.volume = 1.4;  /// 2.0 etc
```

Answer (score 9):

Based on: http://cwestblog.com/2017/08/17/html5-getting-more-volume-from-the-web-audio-api/

You can adjust the gain by using the Web Audio API:

```
function amplifyMedia(mediaElem, multiplier) {
  var context = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext),
    result = {
      context: context,
      source: context.createMediaElementSource(mediaElem),
      gain: context.createGain(),
      media: mediaElem,
      amplify: function(multiplier) {
        result.gain.gain.value = multiplier;
      },
      getAmpLevel: function() {
        return result.gain.gain.value;
      }
    };
  result.source.connect(result.gain);
  result.gain.connect(context.destination);
  result.amplify(multiplier);
  return result;
}

amplifyMedia(document.getElementById('myVideo'), 1.4);
```

The multiplier you pass to the function is at same level as the video volume, 1 being the 100% volume, but in this case you can pass a higher number.

---

Can't post any working demo or JSFiddle because Web Audio API requires a source from the same origin (or CORS compatible). You can see the error in the console: https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/41vrx1z7/1/

> MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions

But I have tested locally and it works as intended.

Comment: Yes it really does work....however it seems to disable the pause function? With this enabled I can play the video but can't pause, rewind or anything like that anymore...it just plays forever. Any ideas why this would be? If I disable the amplifyMedia function call, the video is quiet again but I have full control over pause, fast forward etc again.

Comment: @Hasen you are already testing with Video.js I guess? Probably both don't get along with ease.

Comment: Yes I'm using it with videojs. I thought you had it working your end though? Did you not run into this problem? Its a shame 'cos I thought you had the solution there.

Comment: @Hasen my bad not specifying I did it in vanilla, like the JSFiddle I've linked, but locally.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway. If you have any other ideas please let me know. I'm sure there must be some way to do it. It was great seeing it boosted at least, even if it wasn't practical to use after all.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the source files, rather than trying to boost on the fly using Javascript (for that the Web Audio API answer from @yuriy636 is the best solution) then you can process the video locally using something like [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/).

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:a "volume=1.5" output.mp4
```

This will apply a filter to the `input.mp4` file that just adjusts the volume to 1.5x the input and creates a new file called `output.mp4`.

You can also set a decibel level:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:a "volume=10dB" output.mp4
```

or review the [instructions](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioVolume) to normalize audio etc.

Comment: Ok yeah I realise I can just manually reprocess all the videos but that would take ages and I'd have to do it again and again for any other videos I came across in the future too. Rather laborious. Really it would be so simple to boost the video within the software. Software like VLC can go beyond 100% volume without needing to reprocess the video and save a new file. So I'd really hoped there'd be a way to do it with videojs too. Seems like it should be possible...?

Comment: ffmpeg is pretty quick - it's a one-off process and as you're only touching the audio track it's much less than transcoding video (on a dual core i5 I get about 5x throughput). As I do a bunch of transcodes I just have a 'hot folder' with a powershell script that watches for new files and runs the transcoder profile we need automatically.

Comment: Well if you have a script for it that's doing it for you I guess that might be plausible but I don't have that. Still pretty annoying since really it should just be able to boost the sound and also you might process a video and it may be TOO loud...then you have to do it again and every video would be different. The videos range from 5-20 minutes to 40 or even 90 minutes so it really wouldn't be quick at all.The code from yuriy636 shows that it can certainly be boosted, even if it wasn't practical for use.

Comment: I agree with Offfbeatmammal...use ffmpeg and convert only the audio channel.  I don't use scripts to drive ffmpeg, but my cmd-template would look like:  ffmpeg (whoops...later)

Comment: ffmpeg   -i C:\Users\david\video-in.mp4   -vcodec copy    -acodec mp3   -af "volume=20dB"   C:\Users\david\video-out.mp4                         I don't understand your 'might be TOO loud'. The cmd above sets volume to an absolute value, so they should all then be the same loudness.

Comment: Dave, that's because you don't understand how the volume of sound is perceived by the human ear. Setting all the sounds to the same volume will simply set the highest sound in the whole track to the same level. This might work well for short sound effects but for longer sounds it doesn't work like that. It can also be down to the clarity of speech or the lack of compression of vocals resulting in too may peaks and troughs in the sound. In these cases all you can do is boost beyond the maximum accordingly as needed.

Comment: Its common with youtube videos (which is often what I'm using) because the sound, like the vocals for example are recorded with not the best microphone and then sound is not compressed to smooth out the sound. The sound is sometimes too quiet, sometimes too loud, so the best solution is too boost beyond the limit so you can hear the quiet parts clearly. Other tracks you won't need this at all, or you won't need it so much. That's why I wanted a manual boost option in the software.