# Attempting to increase video volume with gain node, it's silent instead

Tags: javascript, html5-video, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have an html5 video element I'm trying to increase the volume off.

I'm using the code I found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264417/videojs-html5-video-js-how-to-boost-volume-above-maximum)

However there is no sound coming out of the speakers.  If I disable it sound is fine.

```
    videoEl.muted = true //tried with this disabled or enabled

    if(!window.audio)
        window.audio = amplify(vol)
    else
        window.audio.amplify(vol)
```

...

```
export function amplify(multiplier) {
    const media = document.getElementById('videoEl')
    //@ts-ignore
    var context = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext),
      result = {
        context: context,
        source: context.createMediaElementSource(media),
        gain: context.createGain(),
        media,
        amplify: function(multiplier) {
          result.gain.gain.value = multiplier;
        },
        getAmpLevel: function() {
          return result.gain.gain.value;
        }
      };
    result.source.connect(result.gain)
    result.gain.connect(context.destination)
    result.amplify(multiplier)
    return result;
  }
```

That value is set to 3 for testing.

Any idea how why I'm getting no sound?

I also have Howler running for other audio files, could it be blocking the web audio API?

Comment: `media,` in your `result` Object? Maybe you want `media:media,` instead.

Comment: it's the same thing in Typescript